# How do you declare a custom oData annotation

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData service constructed in C# using OData v4 (System.Web.OData). There are some security restrictions on the service: collections which you're only allowed to access if you're authenticated. For a number of reasons including test automation I'd like for the service to be able to declare those restrictions in its $metadata.

Is this possible with OData annotations?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: use the DirectValueAnnotationsManager to set the annotation to an Edm*Constant.

```
EdmModel model = myEntityModel;
EdmEntitySet = myEntitySet;

model.DirectValueAnnotationsManager.SetAnnotationValue(entitySet, "MyNamespace", "AdminOnly", new EdmBooleanConstant(EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetBoolean(false), true));
```

Note that EdmBooleanConstant and EdmStringConstant both produce exactly the same XML output on $metadata.